# Regex won't match all possible groups

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to make a regex that will match the occurrence of any consecutive 4 words separated by a space, however the regex I am using right now seems to only match only whatever is after the first match as shown in the picture.

[image]

I need a Matcher that will let me do:

```
m.group(1) //for "word1 word2 word3 word4"
m.group(2) //for "word2 word3 word4 word5"
m.group(3) //for "word3 word4 word5 word6"
m.group(4) //for "word4 word5 word6 word7"
m.group(5) //for "word5 word6 word7 word8"
m.group(6) //for "word6 word7 word8 word9"
```

Comment: Use `"(?=(\\w+ \\w+ \\w+ \\w+))"` and grab `matcher.group(1)` `while` iterating over the matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, need add \b at the beginning of group 1: (?=(\b\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+))

Comment: @ShenYudong Yeah, since the lookahead will test each position.

Comment: Shorter `(?=(\b\w+(?:[ ]\w+){3}))`